# jquery number counter not stop in scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have some problem on jquery code . this code fade up on scroll i use number counter values in this code

```
countswing = 0;
tiles = $("div .newstats").fadeTo(0, 0);

$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) 
            {
                $(this).fadeTo(2000,1);

                if(countswing<1)
                {
                    jQuery({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 700}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing:'swing', // can be anything
    step: function() { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('#stats1').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue) + "+");
    }
});
jQuery({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 500}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing:'swing', // can be anything
    step: function() { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('#stats2').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue) + "+");
    }
});
jQuery({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 1000}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing:'swing', // can be anything
    step: function() { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('#stats3').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue) + "+");
    }
});
countswing++;

                }



  } 

   });
});
```

but my problem is when i scroll download or scroll up number count not stop its number count again and again i want when i scroll download browser its fade up show then number count only one time when its number count complete then not its count again and again
i also use countswing variable of value 0 for stop counter . like you see in code but its not work it its show same problem .
please tell me how to do only count one time?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle of your problem